# Convert PHP SQL into Laravel query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am new to Laravel, I have used SQL for 2 years but do not understand how to fully migrate to Laravel's queries when using complex SQL.
how would i put the following SQL string into Laravel's query builder, thank you.

```php
$sqlQuery = "SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, cat_name, user_name, topic_date FROM topics, categories, users WHERE topic_by = user_id AND topic_cat = cat_id AND topic_cat = '$topicCat' ORDER BY topic_date DESC limit 10";
```

Comment: Why dont you give it a try first, then get back here if you are still stuck? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#running-database-queries

Comment: Is your `SQL` query working? Maybe it should be a message ambiguous column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, cat_name, user_name, topic_date 
             FROM topics, categories, users WHERE topic_by = user_id AND  
             topic_cat = cat_id AND topic_cat = '$topicCat'
             ORDER BY topic_date DESC limit 10";
```

Before asking questions you need to do some research
no worries I will explain

```
DB::table('users')
->join('categories','users.id', '=', 'categories.user_id')
->join('topics','users.id', '=', 'topics.user_id ')
->where('topics.topic_by','users.id')
->where('topics.topic_cat','categories.id')
->where('topics.topic_cat', $topicCat)
->orderByRaw('topics.topic_date - created_at DESC')
->limit(10)
->get();
```

This what looks like a user's table map with categories and categories is a map with topics because I don't know the Database structure you can join the multiple tables like this also add conditions according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it more simple by creating model, if you create the model and add to top off the file.`users::select('enter the value you want need in table here')->join('categories','users.id', '=', 'categories.user_id')->join('topics','users.id', '=', 'topics.user_id ')->where('topics.topic_by','users.id')->where('topics.topic_cat','categories.id')->where('topics.topic_cat', $topicCat)->orderByRaw('topics.topic_date - created_at DESC')->limit(10)->get();`